# Recursive method in Model class

Tags: angular

I have an Object called Material. Each Material can have a Parent Material.

In my component html I want to show the Parent of the Material and the Parent of the Material recursively. How can I do this and call the method on the simple object ? Is it even possible to put extra get methods in a typescript model class ?
thanks

Angular 5

Comment: While recursion is a great tool for solving certain kinds of algorithms, this does not sound like one of those. You should use an iterative approach. It is also not clear exactly how many parents you want to show... all of them?

Comment: The idea is to show n parent names to show the whole tree structure .

Comment: You might want to have a look at the composite pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible. You can create a special component that will recursively display your object as long as that material has a parent.

### Component

```js
export class ExampleComponent {
  @Input() public material: Material;
  @Input() public index = 0;
}
```

The `index` is used to determine how deep in the tree you are for formatting purposes.

### Template

```html
<div style="display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end;">
  <example *ngIf="!!material.parent"
           [material]="material.parent" [index]="index + 1"></example>
  <div [style.marginRight.px]="10 * index">{{material.name}}</div>
</div>
```

While this works it may be easier to write a method to unroll the tree structure and turn it into an ordered array. This will be an easier mental model to work with then having to think about how to design a recursive template in my opinion.

## [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/79Ir6grWTSipkerf18zA?p=preview)

#### Recursive method for getting ancestors

```js
public getAncestors() {
  if (!this.parent) {
    return [];
  }

  return [this.parent, ...this.parent.getAncestors()];
}
```

Comment: So the bottom line is the start of the recursive call must be on a component member ? Rather than on the Model object ? What if you are looping through an array and want to call the recursive method on the array object each iterattion ?

Comment: You could still define the method on the model object and have it get all of its ancestors. See updated answer for getting ancestor list.

Comment: Cool thanks for the answer. So you cant call a method directly on the model object ? Like material.getParentName()

Comment: You can call a method on the object. You just need to make sure that the object you are working with is the correct type. If you are using a response from the server then it will just be a JSON object. To make a JSON object a `Material` you need to do something like this: `let material = { ...new Material(), ...{/* your JSON object */} }`